# How I can move <hr> tag to center

Tags: html, css

I tried move `<hr> tag` to center , It's moved to center but right direction not in center.

[image: Preview Image]

```css
/* start set fonts */

* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* start general page */

html body {
  background-color: #181333;
}


/* start container */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1939;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}


/* start title */

.title {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fefefe;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}


/* start main line */

.main_line {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">OUR TEAM</h1>
  <hr class="main_line"> </div>
```

What's the problem ? , thanks advance.............................................

Comment: What's the problem? What's the expected output?

Comment: Instead of using `position:absolute;` and `left:50%`, try using `margin:auto` to center it

Comment: using just left: 50% moves it over 50% but that includes the 5% width of the line itself so you need to account for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `margin:auto` instead of `position:absolute`. It lives happily inside the container:

```
.main_line {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  margin:auto
}
```

```css
/* start set fonts */

* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* start general page */

html body {
  background-color: #181333;
}


/* start container */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1e1939;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}


/* start title */

.title {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fefefe;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}


/* start main line */

.main_line {
  display: block;
  width: 5%;
  margin:auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">OUR TEAM</h1>
  <hr class="main_line"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you? It’s the auto that centres it!

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 auto is a great answer but you can also use translate to do it;

```css
/* start set fonts */
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* start general page */
html body {
    background-color: #181333;
}

/* start container */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1e1939;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

/* start title */
.title {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fefefe;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
}

/* start main line */
.main_line {
    display: block;
    width: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1 class="title">OUR TEAM</h1>
<hr class="main_line">
 </div>
```